# How to use input variable in .zshrc alias?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, alias, php

I'm trying to create this alias:

`alias mrc="php artisan make:controller $(user_input) --resource"`

so that I can just type `mrc ControllerName` in the terminal to produce:

`php artisan make:controller ControllerName --resource`

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't see the use of any variable in the code you posted. The  command `user_input` is executed and explanded by the time the alias is defined, because you used double-quotes for the alias definition. Using single quotes would cause this to happen at the time the alias is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I found, it is easier to use a shell function. You can simply define a function where `$1` refers to the first argument given:

```
function mrc() { php artisan make:controller "$1" --resource; }
```

You possibly want to put this in your `~/.zshrc` so you don't have to run this every time you open a new terminal.

If the command should be available in a child shell you also want to use:

```
export -f mrc
```

Now you should be able to type `mrc controllerName` and get the desired output.

For reference (as suggested by nohillside) : [Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter) There you can find both a single and multi-line example of declaring a shell function.

Comment: If there is any problem with this way of doing it, I'd be happy to find another way and/or resolve the issue.

Comment: @Guchen &nohillside Thank you both. The function works without exporting it.